# Get value from an iframe with beautifulsoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to get the temparature value out of [this website](http://www.nordhessen-wetter.de/) with beautifulsoup.
But when I print out the whole text of the soup it only shows me an iframe:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" src="https://www.weatherlink.com/embeddablePage/show/c7ea9161378346e18d2e4c0ea056c55b/summary" width="100%"></iframe>
```

So I try to use the src address that is showen in the iframe:
But it only displays some other code without any code that I can select with beautiful soup :( 
This is my code so far:

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url= 'http://www.nordhessen-wetter.de'
# url = 'https://www.weatherlink.com/embeddablePage/show/c7ea9161378346e18d2e4c0ea056c55b/summary'
u = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(u, 'html.parser')

seitentxt = str(soup)

print(seitentxt)
```

Isn't it possible to get the temperature value out of this code?

Thanks for your help!
Marius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same url that the page uses to get that content. You can find this in the network tab via dev tools.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.weatherlink.com/embeddablePage/summaryData/db22c5a778f14c5da538dc6f3b3ddc0d?ts=1555852879023'
r = requests.get(url).json()
units =  r['currConditionValues'][0]['unitLabel']
current =  str(r['currConditionValues'][0]['value']) + units
high = str(r['highLowValues'][3]['value']) +  units
low = str(r['highLowValues'][4]['value']) + units
print(current, high, low)
```

Use `convertedValue` rather than `value` if you want comma delimiter

---

Temp times:

```
high_time = str(r['highLowValues'][17]['value']) 
print(high_time)
low_time = str(r['highLowValues'][18]['value']) 
print(low_time)
```